# Generating satellite assembly externally

Tags: c#

I have an  third party application in which there are satellite assemblies.
This application is strong name signed. 
I am externally creating new satellite  assembly which is not included by the third party application.
But since the main assembly is strongly signed, my newly created assembly is not been recognized by the application.
How to achieve this ?

Please advice

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to strong-name an EXE.  Go back to the vendor and ask for an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign your satellite assembly as well. This will help in case the main assembly just requires signed DLLs. If it requires DLLs to be signed by the same key as itself, you're probably out of luck.